# Каковы отличия языка C# для разных платформ?

Tags: c#, asp.net-webforms, visual-studio-2010

Посмотрите на этот код:

```
private void tahomaToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        rtbox.Font = new Font("Tahoma", rtbox.Font.Size);
    }
```

Это совершенно валидный код события, взятый из работающей формы Windows Forms.

А теперь посмотрите на этот фрагмент:

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (DropDownList1.SelectedItem == "Times New Roman") this.Label1.Font = new Font("Times New Roman", Label1.Font.Size);
}
```

Он уже взят из кода формы Web Forms. В обоих случаях редактором является VC#2010. Но во втором фрагменте, т.е. в формах для веб, Font - не существует. И я теперь не знаю, как менять в форме шрифт. Кто-нибудь что-то может подсказать?

Answer (score 4):

Начнем с того, что ваша проблема к языку C# отношения не имеет. Язык один и тот же как для WinForms, так и для ASP.NET, ASP.NET MVC, WPF, WCF и чего угодно ещё.

Разница в двух ваших фрагментах кода обусловлена не отличиями языка (он, еще раз повторю, везде одинаков), а тем, что в этих фрагментах используются разные классы из разных сборок, которые только по некоторому (не совсем случайному) совпадению имеют схожие имена и поля/свойства/методы. (В первом случае у вас класс **System.Drawing.Font** из сборки **System.Drawing.dll**, а во втором **System.Web.UI.WebControls.FontInfo** из сборки **System.Web.dll**) Иными словами, не нужно надеяться на то, что взяв код из приложения WinForms и запихнув его в ASP.NET-приложение, вы не получите  кучу ошибок.

Теперь что касается вашего кода. Насколько я понимаю, вы хотите менять шрифт надписи при выборе элемента из выпадающего списка. Ваша ошибка в том, что свойство **Font** у контролов не имеет сеттера, а потому написать что-то вроде

```
MyControl.Font = new Font(...);
```

вы не можете. Однако можете менять свойства самого шрифта. Например так:

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="Drop" OnSelectedIndexChanged="OnChanged" AutoPostBack="True">
        <asp:ListItem>Times</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Arial</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Verdana</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label1" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="10pt"  >Caption</asp:Label>

protected void OnChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Font.Name = (sender as DropDownList).SelectedItem.Text;
}
```

Ну и напоследок - если вы хотите сделать веб-приложение, то лучше используйте для этого ASP.NET MVC, он более удобен, логичен и в лучшей степени разделяет представление и модель. А манипуляции по изменению содержимого одного контрола в зависимости от другого гораздо удобнее проводить с помощью knockout.js

Comment: Исчерпывающий ответ =)
Где-то в другом месте было сказано, что эта возможность может быть реализована только с помощью AJAX. Но AJAX - это что? Это библиотека классов для работы с вэб-формами под C#?

Comment: AJAX (**A**synchronous **Ja**vascript and **X**ML) как таковой не имеет отношения к C# (хотя вполне уместен и даже необходим в ASP.NET MVC приложениях). AJAX - это технология, предназначенная для удобного взаимодействия клиента и сервера "в фоне". Грубо говоря, он позволяет отправлять запросы на сервер и получать ответы без перезагрузки страницы. Современные веб-приложения используют AJAX повсеместно. Например на этом сайте вы можете добавить комментарий, не перезагружая страницу целиком (а вот добавить или отредактировать вопрос или ответ - не можете)

Comment: в принципе WebForm в определенном смысле скрывает многие взаимодействия клиента и сервера, давая программисту иллюзию работы с обработчиками событий как в WinForms, однако "под капотом" у него запрятаны все те же клиент-серверные запросы-ответы, в том числе и с помощью ajax.

Comment: Похоже у меня сложилось неверное представление об этой технологии из-за применения VisualStudio для выполнения работы. По моему скромному опыту могу сказать, что та или иная технология понимается гораздо лучше и глубже, когда работаешь только с кодом.